# Rails Associations for current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I a while ago i read this article: http://pivotallabs.com/users/nick/blog/articles/275-advanced-proxy-usage-part-i which is talking about AR proxy etc..

The author pointed what is my issue now.

This example will describe it.

```
class Gallery
  has_many :images, :class_name => 'Image'
  has_many :my_images, :class_name => 'Image' #, :conditions => "images.user_id == current_user.id" # FIX THIS
end
```

and here

```
class Image
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :gallery
end
```

Notice: I use PostgreSQL

So when you access **my** all images with a gallery: `Gallery.first.includes(:my_images)`

If i want to return all images: `Gallery.first.includes(:images)`

So now how to pass the current user to the conditions in the `has_many`?

**Edit**

```
User
  has_many :images
  has_many :galleries, through: :images
```

Comment: You didn't describe the relation between current user with Gallery and images, so it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: I will edit the question

Comment: Wouldn't it be has_many :galleries 
has_many :images, through :galleries and then access as Spyros says

Comment: I'm asking for eager loading... so it will be load only my images! thats what am asking for...

Comment: This has always bothered me, I've never been able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well, you want to get something like :

```
current_user.galleries.first.images
```

If so, you would just need to create a has_many association between User and Gallery through a third model, possibly named UserGallery.

More information on has many through :

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association